# use globalcompositeoperations on KineticJS 4.7.2

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, kineticjs, globalcompositeoperation

This was answered at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18583431/globalcompositeoperation-with-kineticjs) using KineticJS 4.6.0 providing this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/m1erickson/QcnHa/)

But... any idea how to do this on the latest version of kineticjs?

I tried the same fiddle with kineticjs 4.7.2: http://jsfiddle.net/qNtSg/
I just changed drawFunc with the new API

```
drawFunc: function (context) {
    ... 
    context.fillStrokeShape(this);
}
```

compositing is not working

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**The Kinetic.Shape has changed in recent versions.**

Now the Shape drawFunc receives a wrapper of the context rather than a canvas.

However, the wrapped context still does not support `globalCompositeOperation`.

Therefore, you still need to "cheat" by getting the actual html context (instead of the wrapped context).

Here's how to get the actual html context:

```
drawFunc: function(context) {
    var ctx=this.getContext()._context;
    ....
```

So here's revised code and a Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/m1erickson/h3DGB/

```
        var reveal = new Kinetic.Shape({
          drawFunc: function(context) {
            var ctx=this.getContext()._context;
            ctx.save();
            ctx.beginPath();
            ctx.globalCompositeOperation="destination-out";
            ctx.arc(120,120,75,0,Math.PI*2,false);
            ctx.closePath();
            ctx.fill();
            ctx.restore();
          },
          dragBoundFunc: function(pos) { return(pos); },
          fill: '#00D2FF',
          stroke: 'black',
          strokeWidth:4,
          draggable:true
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

very inspirating answer. My requirments were slightly different but I could do it reading this. Leave a commented fiddle in order to contribute).
I do here cause I can't comment yet due to reputation under than 50  :)

Thanks to MarkE for the inspiration again,
Stupid thing cannot post fiddle without code

Maxi

```
<html>
  <head>
    <style>
      body {
        margin: 20px;
        padding: 20px;
      }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
 </body>
</html>
```

Stupid thing cannot post fiddle without code

http://jsfiddle.net/L7eLR/